# How to deserialize nested JSON in mongo with scala?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, spray, json4s

While creating a small API based on spray.io I was getting data form Mongo database.
In the database data is serialized like so:

```
{
  "name": "Peter",
  "sname": "Jenkins",
  "contacts": {
    "phone": "+1552255",
    "address": "Pendelton st 62"
  }
}
```

My deserialization is done while passing data to case class

```
contacts = monoDBO.getAs[Map[String, String]]("contacts")
```

I am using json4s for deserialization yet no mater as what I try to get the data I get a `nullPoiunter` error. I have tried using case classes json objects and else.

Error is probably very simple yet i just can't get it working.

Comment: What version of json4s are you using?

Comment: I wonder how the library might react when trying to de-serialize "contacts" to a string

Comment: @JasonPearson json4s version is 3.2.5
@AurélienThieriot I have tried `[String, Any]`, `[String, Object]` latter relies on spray-json yet the result was the same null pointer exception to some of the library file

Comment: MongoDBObject is already a Map.

Comment: What is monoDBO? a MongoDBObject?